# Xamarin.iOS Draw a Border for bottom of the UITextField / ViewDidAppear is too late

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, border, viewdidappear

I'm coding in Xamarin.iOs and I'd like to add a border for bottom of the UITextField.

So it's simple, I've googled it and (I personalized it to Xamarin.ios and) I have this code from this [link.](https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/how-to-draw-or-set-a-border-for-particular-side-of-uitextfield-in-ios/comment-page-1/)

```
UITextField _textField = new UITextField();
_textField.Placeholder = placeHolder;
_textField.AutocapitalizationType = autocap.Value;
_textField.AutocorrectionType = uitextAutocorrect.Value;
_textField.BorderStyle = borderstyle.Value;
_textField.SecureTextEntry = secureTextEntry.Value;
_textField.KeyboardType = uiKeyboardType.Value;
return _textField;
```

As you know I cannot put this part of code in constructor of my ViewController and also in ViewWillAppear. So I have to put it in ViewDidAppear, **BUT** it's too late, it means that when I run ViewController, it show the textField without borders, and just after a few milliseconds, the border will appear which is toooo late for me.

Any idea for this display problem?

**EDIT:**

So I ask my question in much more detail :

here is my complete code:

public class ChangePasswordViewController: UIViewController
    {
        //private MainViewModel _viewModel;

```
    private UILabel _oldPasswordLabel;
    private UITextField _oldPasswordTextField;

    private UILabel _newPasswordLabel;
    private UITextField _newPasswordTextField;

    private UILabel _confirmPasswordLabel;
    private UITextField _confirmPasswordTextField;

    private User currentUser;

    private UIButton _saveNewPassworBtn;

    public ChangePasswordViewController(User user)
    {
        currentUser = user;
    }

    private void _saveNewPassworBtn_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do sth
    }


    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 

        //_viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        Title = Texts.ChangePassword;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;



        _oldPasswordLabel = InitUILabel(Texts.OldPasswordTxt, alignment: UITextAlignment.Right);
        _oldPasswordLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(14);
        _oldPasswordLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        _oldPasswordTextField = InitUITextField(Texts.OldPassword, secureTextEntry: true);
        this._oldPasswordTextField.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
            _newPasswordTextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
            return true;
        };
        _oldPasswordTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;




        _newPasswordLabel = InitUILabel(Texts.NewPasswordTxt, alignment: UITextAlignment.Right);
        _newPasswordLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(14);
        _newPasswordTextField = InitUITextField(Texts.NewPassword, secureTextEntry: true);
        this._newPasswordTextField.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
            _confirmPasswordTextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
            return true;
        };
        _newPasswordTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;



        _confirmPasswordLabel = InitUILabel(Texts.ConfirmPasswordTxt, alignment: UITextAlignment.Right);
        _confirmPasswordLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(14);
        _confirmPasswordTextField = InitUITextField(Texts.NewPassword, secureTextEntry: true);
        this._confirmPasswordTextField.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
            textField.ResignFirstResponder();
            return true;
        };
        _confirmPasswordTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;





        _saveNewPassworBtn = InitUIButton(Texts.Save, _saveNewPassworBtn_TouchUpInside, Colors.MainColor, UIColor.White);

        View.AddSubviews(_oldPasswordLabel, _oldPasswordTextField, _newPasswordLabel, _newPasswordTextField,
                         _saveNewPassworBtn, _confirmPasswordLabel, _confirmPasswordTextField);

        //

        //constraints
        var hMargin = 10;
        var hMiniMargin = 5;
        var vMargin = 10;


       View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();



        View.AddConstraints(
            _oldPasswordLabel.AtTopOf(View, 100),
            _oldPasswordLabel.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),

            _oldPasswordTextField.Below(_oldPasswordLabel, hMiniMargin),
            _oldPasswordTextField.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),
            _oldPasswordTextField.WithSameWidth(View).Minus(hMargin * 2),

            _newPasswordLabel.Below(_oldPasswordTextField, vMargin),
            _newPasswordLabel.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),

            _newPasswordTextField.Below(_newPasswordLabel, hMiniMargin),
            _newPasswordTextField.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),
            _newPasswordTextField.WithSameWidth(View).Minus(hMargin * 2),

            _confirmPasswordLabel.Below(_newPasswordTextField, vMargin),
            _confirmPasswordLabel.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),

            _confirmPasswordTextField.Below(_confirmPasswordLabel, hMiniMargin),
            _confirmPasswordTextField.AtLeftOf(View, hMargin),
            _confirmPasswordTextField.WithSameWidth(View).Minus(hMargin * 2),

            _saveNewPassworBtn.Below(_confirmPasswordTextField, vMargin * 3),
            _saveNewPassworBtn.WithSameWidth(View).Minus(20),
            _saveNewPassworBtn.AtLeftOf(View, 10)

        );


        _newPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_newPasswordTextField);
        _confirmPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_confirmPasswordTextField);
        _oldPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_oldPasswordTextField);
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(Texts.Cancel,UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
        {
            this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, false);
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new ProfileViewController(), false);
        }), true);

    }
    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

    }


}
```

In these lines:

> _newPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_newPasswordTextField);
>           _confirmPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_confirmPasswordTextField);
>           _oldPasswordTextField = SetBottomBorderLine(_oldPasswordTextField);

I put the border for my textfields BUT! If I put these line in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear or ViewDidLayoutSubviews, it doesn't show the changes and if I put them in ViewDidAppear, it's shows perfectly with some milliseconds delay (after showing the content of my page!!!). Do you have any solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caused by using `Cirrious.FluentLayouts`.

When we set the Constraints in `ViewDidLoad`, those control will not finish rendering before `ViewDidAppear` .

Print the frame of those textfields in  `ViewDidLoad`, `ViewWillAppear` ,`ViewDidAppear` , you can find that only in `ViewDidAppear` the frame is not equal (0,0,0,0).

To solve the problem, you can add `View.LayoutIfNeeded`  in `ViewDidLoad` to force update the view.

```
View.AddConstraints(
    //xxx
);

View.LayoutIfNeeded(); //Add this 

_newPasswordTextField  = SetBottomBorderLine(_newPasswordTextField);
_confirmPasswordTextField  = SetBottomBorderLine(_confirmPasswordTextField);
_oldPasswordTextField  = SetBottomBorderLine(_oldPasswordTextField);
```

Comment: I've added more details in my question